# Convert Sybase DB dump file .DMP to SQL Server .bak file format and load the file to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sybase

How to Convert Sybase DB dump file .DMP to SQLServer .bak file format and load the file to SQL server ?

Comment: Well, first we need to know what Sybase product and version you are working with.  But let me mention up front that you are going to have to export the data from Sybase, and import it into SQLServer...you can't just convert the files

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can not convert an existing dump file to another format. In such a situation i would use BCP utility to extract each table data manually and import it on SQL Server again.

More information about BCP utility you will find here:

[Sybase ASE 15 BCP Utility](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility195.htm)

[SQL Server BCP Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)